# Linux kernel can't perform relocation for the hardware with ARM Cortex-A78

Tags: linux-kernel, arm64, relocation, armv8, cortex-a

**Linux Kernel Version:** 5.1.39 and above
**Tool chain:**
gcc-linaro-aarch64-linux-gnu-4.9-2014.09_linux (for Linux compilation)
gcc-linaro-aarch64-none-elf-4.9-2014.09_linux. (for Boot code compilation)

**Platform:**
a hardware system with an ARM Cortex-A78 core, an interconnect, a DDR-DRAM and an UART-16550 only

**Question:**
We are trying to boot the Linux kernel on this hardware system.
The bootcode is provided by ARM and modified by us.

It performs below mentioned tasks:

- initialize the memory by initializing the interconnect
- disable MMU and Cache as per the kernel requirements for aarch64
- change the execution level from EL3 to non-secure EL1
- store DTB address in X0 register, as per the kernel requirements
- branch to the memory location, where an uncompressed kernel image is already present

After the control is transferred to the Linux kernel, kernel performs predefined tasks mentioned in its ./arch/arm64/kernel/head.S file.
To track the execution, we print an alphabet from the head.S file itself, after some lines of execution.
From this, we found that the code gets stuck, after it branches to __relocate_kernel label. In particular, it stuck when it tries to load some value from a memory address.

If we disable the relocation from menuconfig, it show same behavior once it reaches "set_task_stack_end_magic()" in ./init/main.c

We can't figure out why exactly this issue is appearing?
Can anyone help us out here?
Feel free if you require further information as well to give suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: arm64 calls relocate_kernel right after enable_mmu.  Most likely there is some problem with the MMU setup.

Comment: @stark, we also suspect the same. But can't figure out the exact issue. Can you suggest some most likely setup mistakes which may be causing the issue ? Please note that, we are using a long-term kernel version, which should already have all the setups, proper.

Comment: MMU setup is based on your hardware design and memory configuration.  Look at all the constants and CONFIG values in __create_page_tables:.